# Visual Studio Memory leaks cannot be traced

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory, memory-leaks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx#NotExistJustToMakeTheAElementVisible

I'm using the above site to purge my project of memory leaks, and I was able to finally eliminate one that had been bothering me for more than a month.

However, when using the

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

directives and trying to set breakpoints based on memory allocation number, using

```
_crtBreakAlloc = 425;
```

for instance, I do not get a break point. My debug output, however, shows:

```
'SMP.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'
The thread 0x2e90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occcont.cpp(922) : {425} normal block at 0x0000000000725180, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <R               > 52 04 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occcont.cpp(922) : {424} normal block at 0x0000000000725100, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <,               > 2C 04 1B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occcont.cpp(922) : {423} normal block at 0x0000000000725080, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <  I             > BC 0C 49 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\occcont.cpp(922) : {422} normal block at 0x0000000000725000, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <j               > 6A 05 16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

There are about 280 of these leaks, I have not listed them all, but I am unable to use the above command to set a breakpoint at any of these allocations. This practice worked for eradicating the other memory leak I mentioned I did fix.

Also, FWIW, I have no idea what this occont.cpp file is, where it is, or what it's doing with my project.

Any information/advice on this matter would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it even remotely possible to eliminate all "reported" memory leaks?  I have used these tools before to look for large leaks, but I'm not sure if everything can be eliminated.

Comment: You know, I was thinking the same thing.... I'm not using any files on the f:\ drive and it's mysterious that they even show up in the report at all. I don't know if these are even real leaks of concern. I have handled all the major leaks previously, it's just these little ones I'm working on now

Comment: Yep, anything in "f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\" is going to be part of Visual Studio or Windows SDK stuff.  Because the memory debugger intercepts absolutely every memory allocation, its very prone to false positives.  It's also not advisable to pay attention to "leaks" found when your program exits because there are plenty of things that don't clean up "properly" because the program is exiting, and its going to be moot in a few milliseconds anyway.

Comment: " It's also not advisable to pay attention to "leaks" found when your program exits" - unless those are leaks caused by you code, and if not  fixed they might accumulate overtime causing memory problems

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `_crtBreakAlloc = 425;` to detect memory leaks, you must set this before allocation number 425 takes place. Clearly this has already taken place by the time you set this so therefore you get no breakpoint.

Assuming you have placed the statement in `main` you can have it execute earlier by placing it *outside* of `main` as a static variable initializer.

```
static int breakAlloc = (_crtBreakAlloc = 425);
```

There is  much in what the commenters say. If the application is exiting, then nothing is technically being leaked at all because all will be reclaimed by the operating system when they process exits. In such a case, cleanup of memory may be a waste of time, and an early exit is a performance enhancement. So this could be by design.

As pointed out in the comments, these allocations are made by library code. So probably the underlying issue is either: 1) there is some sort of underlying library shutdown routine you need to call, and possibly there are other negative consequences from that, or 2) it's a false positive caused by calling `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` too early (maybe these were just about to be cleaned up) or 3) it may even be by design (but probably not).

If all the allocation numbers are low, (< 1000) this indicates that the leak isn't growing, so even if it is an error, you have at least contained it in size. But if this is in a DLL it may still be a problem if the DLL is loaded and unloaded repeatedly, and if it shares the CRT with other DLLs which remain loaded. In such a case the leak will accumulate.